# create a list of documents in excel

Tags: excel

I am managing a project where a large number of documents have to accompany the final product.
Think of manuals to certain off-the-shelf products that are in the product (a boat).

I thought it would be handy to have a list in excel with the documents that have to be shipped with the final product and than a (hyperlink) to the document in question.
All these documenters (mostly pdfs) are located in the same directory.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a little confused... Why not do exactly what you're proposing?

You can create hyperlinks in Excel and you can have those hyperlinks open different format documents - Seems like your idea will work exactly as you want... What's missing?

Comment: @JohnBustos I think wierts is primarily asking about getting a directory of filenames into an excel sheet which is a VBA question in my opinion.

Comment: I am looking for a more automated way of doing this than having to create a list by hand. I am working with in the order of 50 manuals and other documents. SO some automation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you will need to loop through a directory of files and generate a hyperlink next to the file names.

I'd recommend using the fileDialog method to select the files and fill a collection or array and then export each row to a row worksheet.

```
sub writeFilesToWorksheet()
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim ws       As worksheet 

'Set up our new sheet'
set ws = worksheets.add

'Add some headers'
ws.cells(1,1).value = "File Name"
ws.cells(1,2).value = "Hyperlink"

'Select files'
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

        'Add the selected files to the sheet'
        For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
            ws.cells (lngCount + 1, 1).value = .SelectedItems(lngCount)
            ws.cells (lngCount + 1, 2).formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & .SelectedItems(lngCount) & ")"
        Next lngCount
end with

ws.activate
set ws = Nothing

end sub
```

If you want to use the friendly names parameter for the hyperlink you could include something like

```
Dim pos as integer
Dim strFriendlyName as string

pos = InStrRev(.selectedItems(lngCount), "\")
strFriendlyName = Right$(.selectedItems(lngCount), Len(.selectedItems(lngCount)) - pos)
```

and update the second part of the for loop to:

```
ws.cells (lngCount + 1, 2).formula = "=HYPERLINK(" & .SelectedItems(lngCount) & ", " & """" & strFriendlyName & """" & ")"
```

Comment: Nice way of doing it!! +1

Comment: @MMerry I must admit i am new to using a VB script in excel. I know of their existence. I will give this a try

Comment: @MMerry I must admit i am new to using a VB script in excel. I know of their existence. For some reason running this provides me with an error. I do not know if this is of importance but i am trying this on a Mac (OSX 10.9.3) it says: Method 'range' of object '_worksheet" failed

Comment: @wierts I fixed the range error but because you are on a mac you can't use the "Application.fileDialog" command as its windows specific. A quick google suggests that I need to pass a string to AppleScript (Apples sort-of-but-not-quite system wide VBA). I'll keep researching and post a mac specific response. Luckily I use a mac at home and can test it out!